# 42703 postgres error while trying to insert from asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql

I had written this code

```
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO public.\"Customer_Table\"(\"Customer_ID\", \"Location_Name\", \"Item_Name\", \"PhNo\") VALUES(i,'Vijayawada',x, y); ", connection);
```

Here i,x,y are variables.

I am getting an exception:

> {"42703: column \"i\" does not exist"}

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that the code is trying to insert literal `i` into database opposed to `variable i's value` like you want to do.

Here's one way of adding variables into insert query :

It may not necessarily resolve the issue but it should help you send variable's values into insert statement.

```
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO public.\"Customer_Table\"(\"Customer_ID\", \"Location_Name\", \"Item_Name\", \"PhNo\") VALUES(@i,'Vijayawada',@x, @y); ", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", i);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", x);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", y);
```

Comment: Hey Hi @ankit_sharma Thnq very much for the answer... But I getting the same error as well